# Vb.Net - Adding connection string through XML or App File in Class Library

Tags: vb.net

I have got CLASS Library in which I have hard coded CONNECTION STRING.

Please help - how can we add it this through XML or Config File and then reference in CLASS LIBRARY.

And when we deploy dll on PRODUCTION, how to copy that xml/app file or will it be part of DLL ????

Regards

Comment: WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: This is class library which I'm using in SQL Server - SSIS

Comment: Connection strings should be saved inside a .config file used by your application. Is therefore important to know if your application is a normal windows application or a web application because the correct config file is different